# how to use EL (Expression Language) in J2EE project using only HTML5

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, el

I created a simple J2EE project
the web.xml file contain only :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Html5Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And I have a simple index.html page :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML5 PROJECT</title>
</head>
<body>
    **<input value="#{bean.str}"/>**
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Bean.java like :

```
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    String str ;

    public Bean() {
        str ="welcome";
    }
// getter ans setters
```

But the EL (expression language) dosn't work (`**<input value="#{bean.str}"/>**`) !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seams like JSF code. `.html` page does not support JSF EL. For JSF EL you need `.xhtml` page. For fully support HTML5, you should use JSF 2.2 which was released with Java EE 7.

For details, go through this [JSF HTML5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets009.htm#BABGECCJ).

You also need to configure `web.xml` to support JSF.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: So I am forced to use JSF 2.2 ?

Comment: @KarimOukara, For your above example you just need, xhtml page instead of html page.

Comment: I tried with .xhtml and I used <input value="#{bean.str}" />. But the result is => "bean.str" !!!

Comment: To work with JSF, you should start from here, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/webapp003.htm

Comment: thank you for your responses, But I do not want to use JSF. how to use el without using JSF ?

Comment: Use plain old JSPs I guess :s

Answer (score 0):

Use $ instead of # in your expression.

```
**<input value="${bean.str}"/>**
```